# Cant do a proxy

Tags: reactjs

Hey i have a express app with a api route

```
app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Its work !! !! !" });
});
```

And i have a reactjs app with that in package.json

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
```

When i want to go on api route of express app (http://localhost:3001/api) its work but its not work with my reactjs app when i go on (http://localhost:4000/api)
i start my webserver with

```
yarn run clean && cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --host localhost --hot --https
```

The problem can be a problem from react router dom?

Resolved Solution:

In webpack config add proxy to devserver

Answer (score 0):

As you are proxying requests, you can access the API endpoints from within react application (proxy parses requests to API), but nevertheless your API is still on its server (or another port on localhost f.e.)

**Your React app just proxies the request**

Example how to query your data with proxy configured:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      // you can use /api here as you proxi it to your API url
      // f.e. localhost:5000/api
      const response = await axios.get("/api");
      setData(response.data);
    };
    getData();
  }, []);

  // stringify your data in json
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2)}</pre>;
};

export default App;
```